# Linear-fit, how to minimize maximum error rather than average error

Tags: regression, linear

I have some points in 2D space and simply want to fit a line through them (solve for $m$ and $b$ of the equation $y = mx + b$) such that the maximum error for any given point is as small as possible.  This is not least-squares linear regression because my goal is not to minimize the total error among all points.  Instead, I  want to minimize the error of the point that has the worst fit.  Is there an equation for how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

In least squares linear regression you are minimizing the L^2 norm of residuals. What you would like to do is to minimize the L^infinity norm. If you do not mind to have an approximate solution, you can minimize the L^p norm for a large p (say p=100, which should be a good approximation of infinity) and do it numerically with standard gradient methods.

Comment: +1 because this is definite a good point (that the OP is actually looking to minimize the infinity norm) but you could expand on it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

It can be formulated as a linear program and solved using techniques from operations research. A reference is "Linear Optimization and Extensions: Problems and Solutions," by Alevras and Padberg. They call it Chebycheff regression.

Comment: Should that be "Chebysheff"? I've seen about a dozen variant transliterations before (Chebyshev, Chebysheff, Chebyshov, Tchebychev, Tchebycheff, Tschebyschev, Tschebyschef, Tschebyscheff, Tschebyschow or Tschebyschew) but "Chebycheff", though feasible, would be a new one on me!